# Formating Json with php foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, woocommerce

I not found answer like this, please suggest if exits.

my Json must look like this:

```
$data = '{
    "Data": {
            "MerchantName": "xxx",
            "PhoneNumber": "xxx",
            "GrandTotalAmount"xxx",
            "DiscountAmount": 0,
            "TotalAmount": ' . $order->get_total() . ',
            "OrderId": "' . $orderCode . '",
            "Type": 1,
      "returnUrl": "xxx",
            "Products": [
                    {
                            "Title": "test",
                            "Model": "1",
                            "Quantity": 1,
                            "Amount": ' . $order->get_total() . ',
                            "ImageUrl":" ",
                    }
            ],
            "Secret": "xxx"
    }
}';
```

and I need to loop my foreach products inside this json to match json format above:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
  $post_data = array(
      'Title' => $string_key,
      'Model' => $string_value,
      'Quantity' => $string_extra,
      'Amount' => $public,
      'ImageUrl' => $public_contacts);
      $post_data = json_encode($post_data, true);
      echo $post_data;
}
```

so I must get JSON like this inside Products[] above json example:

```
                {
                        "Title": "test",
                        "Model": "1",
                        "Quantity": 1,
                        "Amount": 1,
                        "ImageUrl":" ",
                },
                {
                        "Title": "test",
                        "Model": "1",
                        "Quantity": 1,
                        "Amount": 1,
                        "ImageUrl":" ",
                },
                {
                        "Title": "test",
                        "Model": "1",
                        "Quantity": 1,
                        "Amount": 1,
                        "ImageUrl":" ",
                }
```

Comment: Can you also show how does `$order` look like by doing `print_r($order->get_items())`

Comment: yes, I edited my answer please check it, thank you

Comment: Why aren't you not just using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert the array to a valid JSON object?

Comment: because I need to combine first array and second one from foreach, then send this to another server.